# Improve MariaDB Execution Time

Tags: mysql, mariadb, configuration-management, my.cnf

I have a database with one table and three `fields (id, hash, creation time)`.

This table got around 30 million records, the execution time for a query like

```
SELECT * from `table` WHERE hash='blahblahblah';
```

This query is taking around 40 seconds to execute on a 1vCPU 1GB Ubuntu Server with MariaDB installed no other high usage servers are installed.

Now I upgraded my server to 32GB RAM, SSD and 12 core Xeon physical server with MariaDB alone installed on Ubuntu 20.10 and still, the execution time was similar.

I tried increasing the limits in
50-server.conf file and also increased max memory in
systemctl edit mariadb and also edited mysql/conf.d in
innodb_buffer_pool_size

But still no luck. Is there any way I can improve my MariaDB speed to use entire CPU & RAM to run faster.

Comment: Do you have proper indexes in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` when asking about performance.

It sounds like you are missing `INDEX(hash)`.  (`PRIMARY KEY(hash)` or `UNIQUE(hash)`, if present is such an index.)

Answer (score 1):

> This table got around 30 million records ...
> SELECT * from `table` WHERE hash='blahblahblah'; ...
> This query is taking around 40 seconds to execute

Is the hash column *indexed*?
40 seconds sounds *perfectly reasonable* for MariaDB to trawl sequentially through 30 million records.

BTW, if your table *really is* called `table`, then consider changing it to something else, if for no other reason than you're very, *very* likely to have *more than one* table and having a database full of `table1`, `table2`, `table3`, etc., will start to make your head hurt very quickly.

Also, you should *never* use reserved words as identifiers for tables, columns, etc.
It *will* come back and bite you at some point.